# Regex: Match all characters before '+', or the entire string if '+' is not present

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to match all characters before `+` in a string or if that character is not present, match the whole string.

I've come close, so far I have:

```js
const symbols = ['@ES=107XN+HMUZ', '@NQ=107XN']

symbols.forEach(symbol => { 
  console.log((symbol.match(/.+?(?=[+])/g) || []).join(''))
})
```

As you can see, it matches all characters before `+`, but when `+` isn't present none of the string is matched.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Sam

**Bonus Question:**
How do I push those returned values back into the original array?

Comment: Why not just `/^[^+]*/`? (Am I misunderstanding your requirements?)

Comment: @ruakh You're right, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A positive lookahead requires that the lookahead be matched.

You can use `(?:\+|$)` to match either a `+` or the end of the string. Since you have a non-greedy quantifier before it, it will match whichever comes first.

Also, you should remove the `g` modifier. When the pattern works, it ends up returning an array that includes the entire string, because it finds another match starting from the `+`, and then they all get joined together.

```js
const symbols = ['@ES=107XN+HMUZ', '@NQ=107XN']

symbols.forEach(symbol => { 
  console.log((symbol.match(/.+?(?=(?:\+|$))/) || [""])[0])
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, that's working perfectly! I just edited my question to include: "how do I then push the returned values back into the original `array`?" I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: You can use `.map()` to return an array of all the matches, then use `.concat()` to combine the two arrays.